# Selecting the Difference of two tables

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to do something that I feel should be somewhat simple. I have two select statements:

1. `SELECT concat(st.fname,' ',st.lname) as Fullname, st.parent_phone 
   FROM student as st, grade as g, section as s, semester as sem 
   WHERE st.studentid=g.studentid AND g.sectionid=s.sectionid 
   AND s.semesterid=sem.semesterid AND s.semesterid not in (3, 4)
   Group by Fullname;`

Which returns this (mock data):

[image: selectstatement1]

2. `SELECT concat(st.fname,' ',st.lname) as Fullname, st.parent_phone 
   FROM student as st, grade as g, section as s, semester as sem
   WHERE st.studentid=g.studentid AND g.sectionid=s.sectionid 
   AND s.semesterid=sem.semesterid AND s.semesterid in (3, 4) 
   Group by Fullname;`

Which then returns this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is display the three records that appear in the first statement, but not in the second statement in alphabetical order. I want to basically subtract all the records in statement 2 from statement 1. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
   -- the first subquery goes here
) x
LEFT JOIN (
   -- the second subquery goes here
) y
ON x.full_name = y.full_name AND x.parent_phone = y.parent_phone
WHERE y.parent_phone IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. Could you briefly describe what LEFT JOIN does?